# UNIX Pattern Sequence

Tags: shell, unix, sed

The following scenario is for pattern search using UNIX Shell where the pattern between two strings need to happen and then a new column with sequence need to happen

*Input Data*

```
1|AB|1|2            
2|BC|1|2                          
ID CLOSED                           
3|AB|1|2                
4|BC|1|2                      
ID CLOSED
```

**Query**

As per the data above, we need to add SEQ column after UN and it should add
seq 1 as the first value and sequence 2 to the second part and so on till End.

Expected Output

```
1|AB|1|2|1   
2|BC|1|2|1  
3|AB|1|2|2   
4|BC|1|2|2
```

*Tried solution as first part but isn't giving correct output*

`sed -n '/^ID/,/^ID CLOSED/{p;/^pattern2/q}'`

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

Any particular reason you want to use `sed` for this? It seems like a better fit for `awk`:

```
awk -v{,O}FS='|' '
  BEGIN    { seq = 1 }
  /CLOSED/ { seq++ }
  !/^ID/   { $5=seq; print }'
```

Output:

```
1|AB|1|2|1
2|BC|1|2|1
3|AB|1|2|2
4|BC|1|2|2
```

Comment: Hi Mark, suppose if the metadata isn't available in the data, as I edited the query, what additional changes are required

Comment: your answer was useful, sorry instead of pressing the  usefuly button clicked the not useful, apologies

Comment: Your updates made the program shorter, and now that I've edited it you can change your vote, @Ambitioussignal.

Comment: Many thanks, 've done double votes, Is it possible for you the get the following query also answered if possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68861002/unix-addition-to-column-to-consecutive-null-record?noredirect=1#comment121700776_68861002

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
(
seq=1
echo "ID NAME ID1 ID2 ID3 UN SEQ"
while read id name id1 id2 id3 un; do
    [ "$id $name" = "ID NAME" ] && continue
    [ "$id $name" = "ID CLOSED" ] && { let "seq+=1"; continue; }
    echo "$id $name $id1 $id2 $id3 $un $seq"
done < /path/to/the/datafile
echo "ID CLOSED"
) | column -t -s' '
```

Doing this with just a `sed` instruction is not impossible I think, but a way much harder ;)