# UNIX Addition to Column to consecutive Null Record

Tags: unix

The following requirement is to add the record with Subsequent columns to the previous Record as an additional Column

*Input Data*

```
1|AB|1|20||PAR 1234|||1
1|AB|1|20||PAR 1234|||1
||||SIR 234|||1
1|AB|1|20||PAR 456|||2
1|AB|1|20||PAR 233|||2
||||SIR 236|||1        
1|AB|1|20||PAR 123|||2
||||SIR 236|||1 
||||IL 236|||1
```

**Query**

As per the output below; we need to add SIR 234 in the previous Record as a last column and delete the next line, like wise for SIR 236 and to the last of the file, Wanted to use Awk but not getting how.

Expected Output

```
1|AB|1|20||PAR 1234|||1
1|AB|1|20||PAR 1234|||1|SIR 234
1|AB|1|20||PAR 456|||2
1|AB|1|20||PAR 233|||2|SIR 236   
1|AB|1|20||PAR 123|||2|SIR 111|IL 236
```

*Not to sure how to Try AWK in this scenario*
I tried the very basic ones but is giving an error, awk -F, '{print >
$6".txt"}' file

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried the very basic ones, awk -F, '{print > $6".txt"}' file

Comment: Please edit the question and add what you wrote, and the output it produces.

Comment: Have edited with the output

Comment: You can start, calculating the maximum length of every field, as mentioned in this URL: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118737/find-the-maximum-length-of-characters-in-a-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N:s/\n|//;ta' -e 'P;D' File Name > File B
Awk -F'|' '{$6=$$7 $7;NF=24}1' OFS='|' File B
```

Use the above statement to delete extra columns and add the value to the right place

Comment: Not sure why people have given negative votes without giving an answer, this is a proper query and i have an workable solution for the same. I doubt people who voted know the answer or simple pressed negative button.

Comment: Stackoverflow admin need to take of the people who voted negative votes on this query